# error Undefined function or method 'min' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab, struct, error-handling, mat-file, minmax

I have matrix 3x108 which contains dimension data. I want to find min and max value of my matriks in each row. Here's my code:

```
P = load('grading/dimension.mat');
min_P = min(P,[],3);
max_P = max(P,[],3);
```

but it gives me error:

```
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
??? Undefined function or method 'min' for input arguments
of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa>identifikasi_Callback at 1427
min_P = min(P,[],3);
Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)guikedelaizulfa('identifikasi_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: P is not a matrix of doubles, it is a matrix of structs. Do you want the minimum of one of the fields?

Comment: What is the purpose of `P`? What does it contain?

Comment: @Daniel it contains matriks 3x108 sized from .mat file and I want to find minimum and maximum value of each row.

Comment: @rayryeng P used to load .mat file because I'm using gui right now.
 it contains matriks 3x108 sized from .mat file and I want to find minimum and maximum value of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Using `P=load(...)` the function returns a single struct which contains all variables. Assuming you have used the variable name X when saving, you can access the variable using `P.X`. I recommend to set a breakpoint and take a look at the loaded data using the Variable Explorer or the `fieldnames` function.

Comment: It works, @Daniel! Thanks. But I got same error when I try to subtract the minimum and maximum value with this formula:

P = ((0.8*(P-min_P))/(max_P-min_P))+0.1;

can you help me to point out my mistake? Because the formula worked in my previous project.

Comment: What error? I assume max_P and min_P are vectors? Compare mrdivide and rdivide, I assume you chose the wrong operator.

Comment: I think so @Daniel, but it gives this error: ??? Undefined function or method 'minus' for input arguments
of type 'struct'.

Comment: You again got your struct `P` in the formula. You can't do math with structs.

Comment: I tried change the formula into P = ((0.8*(P.Z-min_P))/(max_P-min_P))+0.1; but it gives me error
 ??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> guikedelaizulfa>identifikasi_Callback at 1429
P = ((0.8*(P.Z-min_P))/(max_P-min_P))+0.1;

Comment: The error message already tells you what is wrong. You can not subtract a vector from a matrix. I do not know what you want to implement.